# Freemarker InvalidReferenceException

Tags: java, freemarker

I am trying to pass a collection to Freemarker:

My Recipient inner class:

```
@Data
private class Recipient {
        private String phone;
        private String languageValue;
}
```

My template:

```
    <#list recipients as recipient> 
        {
            "address": "${recipient.phone}",
            "language": "en"
        }
    </#list>
```

My Java code:

```
List <Recipient> recipientList = new ArrayList <> ();
Recipient r = new Recipient();
r.setPhone("123");
recipientList.add(r);


Template template = new Template("name", new StringReader(myTemplate), new Configuration());
Writer out = new StringWriter();
Map<String, Object> dataModel = new HashMap<>();
dataModel.put("recipients", recipientList);
template.process(dataModel, out);
```

But I am getting this error:

> [pool-1-thread-7] freemarker.runtime: Error executing FreeMarker template freemarker.core.InvalidReferenceException: The following has evaluated to null or missing:==> recipient.phone  [in template "name" at line 1, column 220]

What's wrong? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: For me, most probably, the error says that a Recipient class is not public. Can you make sure that you run the same version you put here? I've just tested it and it works for me.

Comment: I see no problem there. Are you sure that you show things accurately in your question? Like, maybe in the real application you have a `Recipient` where `phone` is `null`.